# Overwrite all values from a table with data from other table

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I am trying to overwrite the data from table A with data from table B.

The main objective is to keep the formats of each column in column A and fulfill with data from column B.

```
Insert Into work.table_A
Select work.table_B
From work.table_B
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is unclear. You mention *table* A and *column* A. Also it is unclear whether you are looking for an update or an insert. Would you please update your question to show sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remake the table? Note that SAS dataaset do not reuse the space created by deleting observations, so if you delete and then insert many times your datasets will get take a lot more disk space.

```
data a;
  set a(obs=0) b;
run;
```

You could use data step with MODIFY statement to delete the records and insert the new ones.

```
data A;
  do until (eof1);
    modify A end=eof1;
    remove;
  end;
  do until(eof2);
    set B end=eof2;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Or you could use SQL if you prefer, just make sure that A and B have the same variables or you know how to create the variables needed for A from the variables in B.

```
proc sql;
  delete * from A;
  insert into A select * from B;
quit;
```